# localhost reverse-proxy using npm's express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, localhost, reverse-proxy

I've a reverse proxy gateway that works perfectly using express-http-proxy when on the cloud.

However, I've been trying to get the system working on localhost so that I can develop faster.

I was hoping I could set up:

```
Gateway on localhost:3001
API on localhost:3002
MobileWeb on localhost:3003
```

All the apps seem to be working on their respective ports on localhost, however when requests that pass through express-http-proxy get a 504 timeout.
I tried reverse proxied the requests to other sites on the internet and found that it worked, however proxying things to localhost:3002, or localhost:3003 didn't get anything forwarded to them.

```
app.get('/', expressProxy('localhost:3003', {
  https: false, //don't use https on localhost
  forwardPath: function(req, res){
    return 'SplashPage';
  }
}));
```

Any suggestions? Is this something that isn't possible with the express-http-proxy package?

Comment: I think what is happening is the port # :3003 is getting stripped from the request. Is there a I've tried to look for a "forwardPort" option but it looks like that isn't supported with express-http-proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was with express-http-proxy and it's tendency to strip the port off of the proxied target and replace it with :80

It would be a great fix for that package to incorporate the option of forwardPort:

Solution: I stopped using npm's express-http-proxy and swapped it out for npm's http-proxy. Seems to be much more robust and certainly has no issues adding the port.